# How to stream to an AWS ECS container (RTMP)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, live-streaming, amazon-transcribe

I am trying to generate transcriptions for a live-stream video. I found this aws sample on [Amazon IVS Auto-captions Web demo](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ivs-auto-captions-web-demo) which seems similar to my use case.

But [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ivs-auto-captions-web-demo#known-issues-and-limitations-%EF%B8%8F) it says that we need to stream to an ECS container. I searched a lot but couldn't find any resource explaining how to do that.

Can someone point me to some resources (docs/articles/videos) from where I can understand how to send a live stream to an ECS container so that I can send it further to AWS Transcribe? Or is there some other architecture that I can use to generate transcriptions for a live stream?

Comment: The solution you linked does what you are asking for, so it is very unclear what other resources anyone could provide you. ECS is just running some software in a Docker container, and that software is listening on a port, and you stream to that port, just like you would if the software was running on any other computer. There's nothing ECS specific about this, they are just using ECS to run the software that is part of that solution.

Comment: Actually I am quite new to this stuff, so sorry for any silly questions but can you provide some resources on how can I send a live stream to a particular port? I mean all that setup stuff. How can I write that "software" you are referring to. I didn't find any of that software code in the repo.